# 50th vs 50nd? Whats the difference?

Tags: grammar

I have a question to ask

**49 artists already joined
Want to be the 50th/50nd ?**

Which one is correct?
What’s the diffrence?
Between th and nd

Comment: The difference is that "th" is correct and "nd" is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These abbreviations are used for indicating how the ordinal numbers are spoken.

Number 0 - zeroth - 0th
Number 1 - first - 1st
Number 2 - second - 2nd
Number 3 - third - 3rd
Number 4 - fourth - 4th

Numbers 5-9 follow the examples of Number 4, and use "th."

All of the "teens" (including 11 and 12) also use "th."

When you get to 20, the pattern continues exactly the same as for the single-digit numbers and repeats forever.

So as Daniel indicated, the difference between "50th" and "50nd" is that "50th" is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your passionate answer ❤️

Comment: I am blind and rely on text-to-speech, with this post I discovered the main synthesizer I use pronounces "50nd" and "50th" the same (both as "fiftieth"). I'm somewhat surprised it doesn't read as "fifty n d" (which one of my other synthesizers does do).